# Determine Galois groups of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory

Determine the Galois groups of the following polynomials over Q.

$f(x)=x^3−3x+1$.

$g(x)=x^4+3x+3$.

$h(x)=x^5+8x+12$.

I have no way to find their Galois groups. I only obtained that since they are irreducible, their Galois groups are transitive subgroups of $S_3$, $S_4$, $S_5$ resp. Should I try all possibilities one by one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, for the first one it is is $S_3$ or $A_3.$ The latter possibility only arises if the discriminant is a perfect square, so you should compute that. For the second polynomial, you need to check whether the discriminant is a square AND whether the cubic resolvent is irreducible (the cubic resolvent for $g$ is $x^3 - 12x - 9$). In fact, the discriminant is the same for the quartic and the cubic resolvent. If the cubic resolvent is irreducible the Galois group is either $S_4$ or $A_4,$ depending on whether the discriminant is a square. For the last polynomial, you should factor it modulo some primes and see what happens. For example, mod $3,$ the polynomial factors as $x(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-1),$ so your Galois group has a transposition, which, presumably, means that it is all of $S_5.$

Comment: For $h(x)$, that the Galois group contains a transposition, it is necessary and sufficient that there is at least one (and hence, at least two) nonreal roots. $5x^4 + 8$ has no real roots so $h(x)$ is monotone giving the conclusion.

Comment: Can you detail why thee modulo factorization guarantees the existance of a transposition? Never seen that reasoning before and it does look interesting.